# ImageField class in django 1.8 not displaying image in the template

Tags: python, django

According to the code the image should be displayed on the `index.html` template but there seems to be some problem with the `img src`

My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models


class Rockinfo(models.Model):
   rock_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="ac/dc")
   rock_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d",default="1992/08/92")
   rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __str__(self):              
       return self.rock_name
```

My `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Rockinfo, Rockvids

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Rockvids
  extra = 10

class RockinfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = [
    ('The Fucking Band',               {'fields': ['rock_name']}),
    ('Image', {'fields': ['rock_img']}),
  ]
  inlines = [ChoiceInline]  
  list_display = ('rock_name', 'rock_img')
  list_filter = ['rank']
  search_fields = ['rock_name']


admin.site.register(Rockinfo, RockinfoAdmin)
```

my application's `urls.py`

```
 from django.conf.urls import url

 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
 ]
```

My project's `models.py`

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
 from django.contrib import admin

  urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^rockinglist/', include('rockinglist.urls',  namespace="rockinglist")),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     ]
```

My `views.py` file

```
   from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
   from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
   from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
   from django.views import generic
   from .models import Rockvids, Rockinfo


   class IndexView(generic.ListView):
   template_name = 'rockinglist/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'latest_rockinfo_list'

   def get_queryset(self):
       return Rockinfo.objects.order_by('-rank')[:5]
```

The `index.html` file

```
   {% if latest_rockinfo_list %}
   <ul>
   {% for rockinfo in latest_rockinfo_list %}
   <h1>{{ rockinfo.rock_name }}</a></li>
   <img src="img\{{ rockinfo.rock_img }}" alt="ac/dc">
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   {% else %}
   <p>No</p>
   {% endif %}
```

I think the problem is with the root of the image.Somehow django cannot reach the images.I want to display the `rock_name` along with the associated `rock_img`. Can someone help me figure this out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The URL in `src` should have forward slashes (`/`) not reverse (`\\`).

Comment: Did that.Still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Also, the `default` date is wrong. It reads `1992/08/92`. I think you meant `29` instead of `92`. (Although, this hasn't got anything to do with the problem).

Comment: What is the current path you're getting in your template, for `"img/{{ rockinfo.rock_img }}"`? That should tell you what's missing, especially if you compare it with where the images are actually stored on disk. At a guess, you might be missing `{{ MEDIA_URL }}`.

Comment: As of now according to `upload_to` the images from ImageField are being stored at final project/2015/06/05. I realize this is wrong but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: And what is `rockinfo.rock_img`? What are `MEDIA_ROOT` & `MEDIA_URL`? Where does `final project` come from; `MEDIA_ROOT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your project's urls.py, add this:

```
# your other imports here ...
# ...
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLs ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In your settings.py file, make sure you have this:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

In your templates:

```
<img src="{{ rockinfo.rock_img.url }}" alt="ac/dc">
```

---

**Note:** If `BASE_DIR` is not defined in your settings, put this on top of your settings file:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if `MEDIA_URL` is provided in you settings. Django doesn't server media during development so you have to have the following in your project's `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

after this you can access your image in template with

```
{{ rockinfo.rock_img.url }}
```

Comment: You don't need `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` if you are using `rock_img.url`. Because the `url` method automatically does that.